# Intermittent Event Firing VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, visual-studio-2008

I encountered a strange problem at work today, and I'm not sure where to go next.

I work on software (VB.NET) that runs on multiple computers over a network. On one (and only one) of the computers, the click event of one of the buttons will only fire intermittently (I inserted a breakpoint to verify this). The button must can be clicked anywhere from 1 to upwards of 10 times before the event actually fires.

The weird part is that whenever I remote desktop into another computer over the network and click the button (from the faulty computer), the same problem will occur. However when I remote desktop into the faulty computer from one that does not display the problem, the problem does not occur anymore.

The faulty computer is running Windows 7 32-bit and the software was developed using Visual Studio 2008 Express, similar to other computer that run the same software without a problem.

Here is the code for the event handler:

```
    Private Sub cmdStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click
        ...
    End Sub
```

Also, this is not the only button the click event won't fire for in the program, it will only fire intermittently for other buttons in the program too (but again only from the one computer).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Sounds like a broken mouse on the problem computer.

Comment: I tried multiple mice, and this did not fix the issue. The event will usually fire but it may take several clicks.

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like either a hardware issue or a driver issue. Or perhaps a rogue application that's installed a mouse hook of some kind. Do you have trouble with that computer when working with other programs?

Comment: I haven't noticed any issues with other programs.

Comment: It could be an issue with the mouse port, if its USB try a different port.  Considering the issue happens over RDC as well, it's very unlikely it has to do with the program.

Comment: I tried using the keyboard to click the button when it's in focus (pressing spacebar) and the same problem occurs leading me to believe it's not just the mouse causing the problem.

Comment: I wonder if `spacebar` is implemented as some kind of virtual mouse click and therefore subject to the same problem? Is there a system restore point on the problem machine that could go back to before the problem started?

Comment: I tried restoring to week ago when there was no problem, but yet again, the problem is still there. Today I installed VB 2010 to see if it was only a problem with VB 2008, and before even importing the project to VB 2010 it started working. There could've been a missing component of the .NET framework on that computer, or the program may just be going through a phase where it works for a few hours then stops again. I'll check again tomorrow to see if the problem has reoccurred or not. Thanks for the suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my program. It was a program that recorded audio. I had to click the button at least 23 times before it fired (yes, I had the time and patience to find this out). I tried reinstalling the program on the faulty computer, but to no avail. So I backed up my project files, upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 and targeted my application for the .NET framework version 3.5. This version is pretty common and most computers have it, including old PCs running XP. Before you go upgrading, try reinstalling. 
Hope this helps :)